# Change hotend thermistor input in Marlin

Tags: prusa-i3, marlin, hotend, thermistor

I have a Marlin driven Prusa i3 clone, by accident I cut through both thermistor wires for the hotend while it was powered on. The Arduino reset and the hotend thermistor no longer work.

Since there is a spare thermistor input on the RAMPS board I was wondering if I can change the input pin assigned to the hotend thermistor in the software? I've looked around (the code and the internet) and so far have only found out how to assign the thermistor type for the spare input, not how to tell Marlin to make `temp_sensor_2` be the input used for the hotend?

If anyone could help me figure out how to change the hotend thermistor input number I would be greatly appreciative!

Answer (score 4):

In [pins_RAMPS.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/bugfix-1.1.x/Marlin/pins_RAMPS.h) you find which pins are used for which thermistor:

```
//
// Temperature Sensors
//
#define TEMP_0_PIN         13   // Analog Input
#define TEMP_1_PIN         15   // Analog Input
```

To use the other thermistor, you would need to swap the numbers:

```
//
// Temperature Sensors
//
#define TEMP_0_PIN         15   // Analog Input
#define TEMP_1_PIN         13   // Analog Input
```

Comment: Well I am having same problem, I changed the pin no and pin 15 is working but all other pin (12, 13, 14) are not working. I am using Anycubic Trigorilla... Can I use any other pin for this?