# Thermal runaway when power on

Tags: hotend, tevo-tarantula

I get the error "`Thermal runaway on E1. Reset printer.`" today on my Tevo Tarantula when powering on the printer. The display shows the error and the speaker beeps loudly everytime I power on the printer or reset it.

I use the firmware
https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula, because I can switch E0 heat nozzle to E1 wires, without soldering; PID's for nozzle were configured, and works fine before I replaced the power supply.

Recently my power supply was broken, and today I installed new power supply, clean nozzle, several times start bed leveling, and on fourth time of homing error appeared.

Power supply voltage tested with a multimeter and the voltage of power supply is 12.06V.

Note: several times printer started bed leveling.

Comment: Do note that Marlin internal naming for extruders starts with 0 (zero), but, error reporting and menu use naming starting 1 (one).  Thermal runaway should only be triggered when heating the hotend. Strange that this happens when you turn on the printer or after levelling.

Comment: Agree, it is strange. I will test ceramic heater tomorrow. I think that short circute is at ceramic heater either at hotend or board connection. I will replace it if so. I will comment result of tests.

Comment: Issue is solved. Root cause was at broken thermistor circute at board and broken thermistor. I disconnect all wires and power, measure board nest thermistors  resistance: E0 = ~120 Oms, (E1 and Bed) = ~700 Oms. I changed pins at Marlin for Tevo pins_RAMPS.h as at https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10208/change-hotend-thermistor-input-in-marlin, changed thermistor at everything prints fine.

Comment: When I last updated my Ender 3 pro I also downloaded a boot loader which set certain parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is solved!

Root cause was a broken thermistor circuit at board and broken thermistor.

I disconnected all wires and power, measured board and thermistors resistance: E0 = ~120 Ω, (E1 and Bed) = ~700 Ω. I swapped pins for `TEMP_0_PIN` and `TEMP_1_PIN` within Marlin for Tevo firmware at `pins_RAMPS.h` as described in answer on question [Change hotend thermistor input in Marlin](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10208/change-hotend-thermistor-input-in-marlin), changed thermistor and everything prints fine.